# Vectorized way for applying a function to a dataframe to create lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen few questions like these

[Vectorized alternative to iterrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534782/vectorized-alternative-to-iterrows) , 
[Faster alternative to iterrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149735/faster-alternative-to-iterrows) , [Pandas: Alternative to iterrow loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963601/pandas-alternative-to-iterrow-loops) , 
[for loop using iterrows in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297341/for-loop-using-iterrows-in-pandas) , [python: using .iterrows() to create columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458794/python-using-iterrows-to-create-columns) , [Iterrows performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418280/iterrows-performance). But it seems like everyone is a unique case rather a generalized approach.

My questions is also again about `.iterrows`.

I am trying to pass the first and second row to a function and create a list out of it.

**What I have:**

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns that look like this.

```
         I.D         Score
1         11          26
3         12          26
5         13          26
6         14          25
```

**What I did:**

where the term `Point` is a function I earlier defined.

```
my_points = [Points(int(row[0]),row[1]) for index, row in score.iterrows()]
```

**What I am trying to do:**

The faster and vectorized form of the above.

Comment: So you want to apply a function on values in a `DataFrame`, and return a list? Try `DataFrame.apply` - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the solution ! Thanks¨

Comment: The way you wrote the sentence actually made me understand my question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try list comprehension:

```
score = pd.concat([score] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

def Points(a,b):
    return (a,b)

In [147]: %timeit [Points(int(a),b) for a, b in zip(score['I.D'],score['Score'])]
1.3 ms ± 132 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [148]: %timeit [Points(int(row[0]),row[1]) for index, row in score.iterrows()]
259 ms ± 5.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [149]: %timeit [Points(int(row[0]),row[1]) for row in score.itertuples()]
3.64 ms ± 80.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This reduced my processing time from 21 minutes to 31 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: @Matthew - ya, try `apply`, but in my opinion it should be slowier, because some security checks.

Comment: it seems like itertuples is also very close to the performance of this one, in my case.

Comment: .apply in this is not applicable for my case

Comment: @Matthew - yes, only a bit slowier - add to timings in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is actually not about how you iter through a `DataFrame` and return a list, but rather how you can apply a function on values in a `DataFrame` by column.

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis` set to `1`:

```
df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

To put in a list, it depends what your function returns but you could:

```
df.apply(Points, axis=1).tolist()
```

If you want to apply on only some columns:

```
df[['Score', 'I.D']].apply(Points, axis=1)
```

If you want to apply on a `func` that takes multiple `args` use `numpy.vectorize` for speed:

```
np.vectorize(Points)(df['Score'], df['I.D'])
```

Or a `lambda`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: Points(x['Score'], x['I.D']), axis=1).tolist()
```

Comment: this does not work as the function needs to take in 2 values and it needs to take it from some columns and not everything

Comment: It wasn't obvious from your question that your `DataFrame` contained more columns than `ID` and `Score` so I don't think that is a valid point. But, you can just `apply` by selecting the `columns` you want first. This can be used in a function that takes multiple values, but it depends on how the function is written - you didn't post it in your question.

Comment: My apologies, I wanted to thank you for actually rephrasing my question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried the method `.itertuples()`?

```
my_points = [Points(int(row[0]),row[1]) for row in score.itertuples()]
```

Is a faster way to iterate over a pandas dataframe.

I hope it help.

Comment: This one also fits very well! Thank you

Comment: The jezrael answer seems to be the fastest @alejandro but thank you for your time!